# Cant ping DNS via OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, pfsense

Can anybody help shed some light on the current issue I am facing?

I have a pfSense box running openVPN. My laptop can connect without a problem to the VPN as well as the internet. The only IP within the network I cannot ping is the DNS Server (Windows 2016). My laptop connection has been given the ip of the DNS server.

I have the openVPN server set to include:
DNS Default Domain (True)
DNS Default Domain: Medicore.Lan
DNS Server Enable (True)
DNS Server 1: IP that is unreachable.

Any ideas why this one IP, in particular, would not be accessible? The subnet for the network card is 255.0.0.0.

**Edit:**
nslookup Results

> C:\Users\David-Laptop>nslookup \fileserver DNS request timed out.
>       timeout was 2 seconds. Server:  UnKnown Address:  10.10.10.10
>
> DNS request timed out.
>       timeout was 2 seconds. 
>   DNS request timed out.
>       timeout was 2 seconds.
>   *** Request to UnKnown timed-out

Comment: It can be as simple that the server itself (due to OS / local firewall  settings ) doesn't respond to ICMP echo reply packets. Do the actual services on that server respond?

Comment: When I am connected on the lan the server responds.

Comment: Is openvpn configured as bridged vpn or routed? If it's routed, do your hosts have all necessary routes? Also, if it's routed, your client lies in a different network than server, so firewall on the server might be set up to answer to packets from lan and to not answer to packets from other network.

Comment: Why do you need to ping the DNS server?

Comment: Because its also our AD server. We have A Records set up to resolve network locations.

Comment: Being able to ping the server doesn't tell you anything about whether or not AD and DNS are working. Are you experiencing AD or DNS problems?

Comment: I am just not able to resolve hostnames that have custom A records in the DNS.

Comment: OK. Troubleshoot that problem. You'll waste a lot of time chasing why ping doesn't work (it doesn't by default). Have you used nslookup to troubleshoot DNS?

Comment: I have tried nslookup and added the results to the question. I can see the Tap Adapter gets the IP of the DNS server in the properties.